# Why is the x-axis text size not getting bigger with axis.text.x in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to increase the font size of the tick numbers of the x-axis, but is not recognised by theme(), why is it?
ARe functions overriding each other?

```
    df <- data.frame('Variable'=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,7,7,7),
                         'value'=c(10,11,12,14,12,14,16,12,18,21,19,23,24,25,26,27,25))    


ggplot(df, aes(x = Variable, y = value)) +
             geom_jitter(alpha = 0.8, color = "tomato") +      
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 25,color="black"),
                 axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12,color="black" ))+    
    theme_classic()+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:7)
```

[image]

Comment: Put your theme adjustments after `theme_classic()`. Otherwise they have no effect as you are overwriting them by the `theme_classic` defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit : stefan was quicker in the comment section.**

Put the `theme()` after `theme_classic()`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Variable, y = value)) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.8, color = "tomato") +      
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:7) + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 25,color="pink"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12,color="black" ))
```

[image]